# Erlang: Writing mnesia table to .csv one record per line

Tags: csv, erlang, export-to-csv, mnesia

I have got a Mnesia table which consists of the following format:

`-record(state, {key, tuple, state, timestamp, fin_from}).`

The entries look like follows (read with `ets:tab2list(Tab)`):

```
[{state,{80,43252,tcp,tcp_syn_received,{192,168,101,5},{192,168,101,89}},
        {80,43252,tcp,{192,168,101,5},{192,168,101,89}},
        tcp_syn_received,1463850419221,undefined},
 {state,{80,41570,tcp,tcp_syn_received,{192,168,101,5},{192,168,101,89}},
        {80,41570,tcp,{192,168,101,5},{192,168,101,89}},
        tcp_syn_received,1463850403214,undefined},
...]
```

I would like to write these data to a .csv file with one entry per line - preferred with the following format:

```
state,80,43252,tcp,tcp_syn_received,192.168.101.5,192.168.101.89,80,43252,tcp,192.168.101.5,192.168.101.89,tcp_syn_received,1463850419221,undefined
state,80,41570,tcp,tcp_syn_received,192.168.101.5,192.168.101.89,80,41570,tcp,192.168.101.5,192.168.101.89,tcp_syn_received,1463850419221,undefined
```

There should be a line break after `undefined`.
I tried using the following code (while `Content = ets:tab2list(states)`):

```
do_logging_async(File, Format, Content, Append)->
F = fun() ->
    file:write_file(File, io_lib:fwrite(Format, [Content]), [Append])
end,
spawn(F).
```

However, I cannot get anything similar to my output.
The data should afterwards be evaluated with R.

**UPDATE**: The key was to read the table line by line and parse it with `~w` but not `~p`. I ended up with the following solution (which produces a slightly different output, however, there is less redundant data):

```
do_state_logging(File, EtsAsList) ->
% write header (columnnames)
file:write_file(File, io_lib:fwrite("~w,~w,~w,~w,~w,~w,~w,~w~n", [record,dstPort,srcPort,proto,dstIP,srcIP,state,timestamp]),[append]),
case EtsAsList of
    [] ->
        ok;
    _ ->
        F = fun({Record,_Key, 
            [P1, P2, Proto, {D_Ip_1,D_Ip_2,D_Ip_3,D_Ip_4}, {S_Ip_1,S_Ip_2,S_Ip_3,S_Ip_4}],
            State, Timestamp, _}) -> 
            file:write_file(File, io_lib:fwrite("~w,", [Record]),[append]),
            file:write_file(File, io_lib:fwrite("~w,~w,~w,", [P1,P2,Proto]),[append]),
            file:write_file(File, io_lib:fwrite("~w.~w.~w.~w,", [D_Ip_1,D_Ip_2,D_Ip_3,D_Ip_4]), [append]),
            file:write_file(File, io_lib:fwrite("~w.~w.~w.~w,", [S_Ip_1,S_Ip_2,S_Ip_3,S_Ip_4]), [append]),
            file:write_file(File, io_lib:fwrite("~w,", [State]),[append]),
            file:write_file(File, io_lib:fwrite("~w", [Timestamp]),[append]),
            file:write_file(File, ["\n"],[append]) 
        end,
        lists:foreach(F, EtsAsList)
    end,
    io:format("Finished logging of statetable to file: ~p~n" , [File]).
```

Thanks to the answer who pushed me to this idea.

Comment: Is it possible for you to save your ets values as lists and not tuples? i.e. `[80,43252,tcp,tcp_syn_received,[192,168,101,5],[192,168,101,89]],
        [80,43252,tcp,[192,168,101,5],[192,168,101,89]],
        tcp_syn_received,1463850419221,undefined]`.  Because then it will be simpler to flatten and write each flatten record as a line.

Comment: Yes I could do this. But how do I parse the single lines (and lists) afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you change your ets records values to be in lists and not tuples you can use this code to write your ETS Table to a file.

```
do_logging_async(File, EtsAsList) ->
    F = fun({Key, Value}) -> 
        file:write_file(File, [atom_to_list(Key) ++ ","],[append]),
        write_value(File,lists:flatten(Value)),
        file:write_file(File, ["\n"],[append]) 
    end,
    lists:foreach(F,EtsAsList).


write_value(_File, []) -> ok;
write_value(File, [H|T]) ->
    case is_integer(H) of
        true -> file:write_file(File, [integer_to_list(H)],[append]);
        false -> file:write_file(File, [atom_to_list(H)],[append])
    end,
    case T=:=[] of
        true -> ok;
        false -> file:write_file(File, [","],[append])
    end,
    write_value(File,T).
```

`do_logging_async/2` takes every `{Key, Value}` pair. First, it writes the `Key` to the file and then it runs `write_value/2` on the `Value`, at the end of each pair it writes `\n`.

`write_value/2` takes the flatten value list (assuming it is a flatten list that contains only integers and atoms) and writes it to the file.

Comment: I adapted it to my format: `do_logging_async(File, EtsAsList) ->
    lists:foreach(fun({state, Key, Key_no_state, State, Timestamp, _Val4}) -> 
        %io:format("Writing during this Iteration: { Key, Key_no_state, State, Timestamp, _Val4} ~p~n",[{Key, Key_no_state, State, Timestamp, _Val4}]),
        file:write_file(File, [Key ++ ","],[append]),...
        write_value(File,lists:flatten([Timestamp])),
        file:write_file(File, ["\n"],[append]) 
    end,
    EtsAsList).`
However, only timestamps are written. file:write_file() return {error, badargs}.. dunno how to go on..

Comment: You need to change your ets `{Key, Value}` pairs to be `{state, [Key, Key_no_state, State, Timestamp, Fin_from]}` and then just use my code as is and it should work.